# Problems with for loop iteration on arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I cannot seem to echo the contents of my arrays. For some reason, only the 2nd value from all of my arrays are being displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The php code is as follows:

```
<?php
// Characters from each item 
$char = 200;
echo '<table cellpadding="0" align="left" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="#585858" width=100%>';
foreach ($xml->Game as $Game) {
    $Date              = $Game->Date;
    $AwayTeam          = $Game->AwayTeam;
    $HomeTeam          = $Game->HomeTeam;
    $AwayRotation      = $Game->AwayRotation;
    $HomeRotation      = $Game->HomeRotation;
    $Total             = $Game->Total;
    $OverPrice         = $Game->OverPrice;
    $UnderPrice        = $Game->UnderPrice;
    $Line              = $Game->Line;
    $AwayTeamPrice     = $Game->AwayTeamPrice;
    $HomeTeamPrice     = $Game->HomeTeamPrice;
    $AwayTeamMoneyLine = $Game->AwayTeamMoneyLine;
    $HomeTeamMoneyLine = $Game->HomeTeamMoneyLine;
    // # items to display 
    $count             = 20;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $AwayTeamSpread         = " ";
        $HomeTeamSpread         = " ";
        $arrayDate              = $Date;
        $arrayARotation         = $AwayRotation;
        $arrayHRotation         = $HomeRotation;
        $arrayAwayTeam          = $AwayTeam;
        $arrayHomeTeam          = $HomeTeam;
        $arrayTotal             = $Total;
        $arrayLine              = $Line;
        $arrayOverPrice         = $OverPrice;
        $arrayUnderPrice        = $UnderPrice;
        $arrayAwayTeamMoneyLine = $AwayTeamMoneyLine;
        $arrayHomeTeamMoneyLine = $HomeTeamMoneyLine;
        $arrayAwayTeamPrice     = $AwayTeamPrice;
        $arrayHomeTeamPrice     = $HomeTeamPrice;
        $arrayLine              = $Line;
        $LineStrip              = str_replace("-", " ", $arrayLine);

        if ($arrayHomeTeamMoneyLine > 0); {
            $AwayTeamSpread = "-";
            $HomeTeamSpread = "+";
        }
        if ($arrayAwayTeamMoneyLine > 0); {
            $AwayTeamSpread = "+";
            $HomeTeamSpread = "-";
        }
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>$arrayDate[$i]</td><td><table><tr><td>$arrayARotation[$i]</td></tr><tr><td>$arrayHRotation[$i]</td></tr></table></td><td><table><tr><td>$arrayAwayTeam[$i]</td></tr><tr><td>$arrayHomeTeam[$i]</td></tr></table></td><td><table><tr><td><input type='checkbox'/> $arrayAwayTeamMoneyLine[$i]</td></tr><tr><td>$arrayHomeTeamMoneyLine[$i]</td></tr></table></td><td><table><tr><td>$AwayTeamSpread $LineStrip ($arrayAwayTeamPrice)</td></tr><tr><td>$HomeTeamSpread $LineStrip ($arrayHomeTeamPrice)</td></tr></table></td><td><table><tr><td>Over $arrayTotal</td></tr><tr><td>Under $arrayTotal</td></tr></table></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

This is the 1st part of my php code, sorry to mix them up. I declare all of my arrays and variables in this section of the coding.

```
<?php
require_once('db-config.php');
// rss page for Testing -  
$feed_url = "http://www.sportsbooks.com/lines/cgi/lines.cgi?tem=parse&sport=203&ct=text/xml&type=";
$xml      = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);
//Connect to mysql server  
$link     = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}
$arrayDate              = array(
    ''
);
$arrayLine              = array(
    ''
);
$arrayLineStrip         = array(
    ''
);
$arrayOverPrice         = array(
    ''
);
$arrayUnderPrice        = array(
    ''
);
$arrayARotation         = array(
    ''
);
$arrayHRotation         = array(
    ''
);
$arrayAwayTeam          = array(
    ''
);
$arrayHomeTeam          = array(
    ''
);
$arrayAwayTeamPrice     = array(
    ''
);
$arrayHomeTeamPrice     = array(
    ''
);
$arrayAwayTeamMoneyLine = array(
    ''
);
$arrayHomeTeamMoneyLine = array(
    ''
);
$Date                   = (string) $xml->Date;
$AwayTeam               = (string) $xml->AwayTeam;
$HomeTeam               = (string) $xml->HomeTeam;
$AwayRotation           = (string) $xml->AwayRotation;
$HomeRotation           = (string) $xml->HomeRotation;
$Total                  = (string) $xml->Total;
$OverPrice              = (string) $xml->OverPrice;
$UnderPrice             = (string) $xml->UnderPrice;
$Line                   = (string) $xml->Line;
$AwayTeamPrice          = (string) $xml->AwayTeamPrice;
$HomeTeamPrice          = (string) $xml->HomeTeamPrice;
$AwayTeamMoneyLine      = (double) $xml->AwayTeamMoneyLine;
$HomeTeamMoneyLine      = (double) $xml->HomeTeamMoneyLine;
$Title                  = (string) $xml->Title;
?>
```

Comment: This is my first time using stackoverflow.. I understand I may be new to programming, may not know how to properly format code yet, but there's no reason to treat a new user like this.

Comment: Per XMen, using var_dump I can see that my other values are being returned as NULL. I'll do some more research, thanks for at least being courteous.

Comment: @BlaineHurtado: I understand, and apologize. Let me see if I can find anything wrong with your code. Welcome to SO! In your code where is $arrayDate, $arrayARotation etc getting created?

Comment: @Raidenace thanks for your hospitality. I joined this forum to learn and hopefully give back one day! I understand how most members who frequent might mix up my lack of skill for someone looking for a handout, I see it a lot :/ Sorry I forgot to add my 1st part of php code!

Comment: @BlaineHurtado welcome to SO. Formatting your code properly is pretty important for readability and debugging, and there's no reason to not do it even when you're new. I've done it for you in this question.

Comment: @sachleen thanks for the welcome and formatting of my code. I've taken note of proper format and definitely understand where you're coming from. I'll keep working on my techniques until they're acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run foreach like

```
foreach ($xml->Game as $Game=>$GameValue) {
    // print $Game and $GameValue here to test the output ;
}
```

if u get array you can iterate more

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ended up fixing it without even having to use an array! Will definitely keep your answer in mind though!